# ArrayList conflicts with type in Netbeans and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, netbeans

This simple tutorial code I'm trying to run won't work in Eclipse or Netbeans. Eclipse says `java.util.Arraylist` conflicts with a type defined in the same file and the netbeans error says this:

> "arraylist.ArrayList is already defined in this compilation unit  at
>   arraylist.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:5)"

```
package arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList();

        listTest.add("first item");
        listTest.add("second item");
        listTest.add("third item");
        listTest.add(7);

        Iterator it = listTest.iterator;

        while (it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: I didn't type the asterisks beside ArrayList. When I selected italics in the question draft it put them in for some reason. They are in italics in Netbeans

Comment: Start using Generics and realize their power..!

Answer (score 2):

Your class name itself is ArrayList. Hence if you want to use any other class with same name from different package, you need to write like java.util.ArrayList.

`List<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Class name are conflicting.

Comment: Great, thanks Ashish. It runs now. I was trying to give the class a meaningful name, but it can't be the same as a class I want to import into the project

Comment: Should have named your `Class` something like `ArrayListExample` or `ArrayListTest`.